# How to set PATH in Ubuntu 17.10 for custom path

Tags: linux, path, environment

I made a folder called bin in `/home/USER/bin` on this, I created a file called `hello` ( for example) with this code:

```
#!/bin/bash    
echo My first program
```

I did execute `export PATH=$PATH":$HOME/bin"` and then `$ . ~/.bashrc`, but when I restarted the PATH is restored to default.

How can I resolve it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user bin directory should already be added to your path by the ~/.profile script.

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin directories
PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

Did you add the export line to your ~/.bashrc file?

```
export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: Hi Corey, thank you for your reply, if I already added export path in  `~/.bashrc` It works, but I need to run on my terminal `export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"` when I sytem restart  It is restored to default PATH and  not worked for me

Comment: How are you running Ubuntu?  Are you booting into the desktop environment?  Does ~/.profile exist?  Does ~/.profile references ~/.bashrc ?

Comment: I have Ubuntu desktop environment and access to this is for ssh, and yes, the `~/.bashrc` `~/.bash_profile` `~/.profile` exist.

Comment: I can only guess that another ~/.bash_profile or other file exists that is preventing ~/.profile from running and executing ~/.bashrc in your login session.

Comment: Corey, I did try in other pc, the PATH export good, but only work for local user, when run with root user, It not work, do you know why happen?

Comment: Maybe because root's .bashrc does not have this change?

Comment: Corey, I'm thinking that It's not possible, but I have already installed with other software and It work for me, I'm trying to develop a npm module